# can you await a function not defined as async but declared new Promise inside of it?

Tags: javascript

We have this in our code:

```
const sqlUpsertRecommendations = recommendationsArray => {
// eslint-disable-next-line no-new

  new Promise(resolve => {
    const insertStatus = {
      ....
    };
    if (!recommendationsArray.length > 0) {
      resolve({
        error: false,
        results: insertStatus,
        localMessage: 'recommendationsArray.length = 0',
      });
    }

    insertStatus.arrayEmpty = false;

    dbConfig.transaction(txn => {
      for (let i = 0; i < recommendationsArray.length; i++) {
        const {
          id,
          recommendation_attribute,
          recommendation_value,
          segment_id,
          target_attribute,
          target_value,
          is_deleted,
          updated_at,
          name,
          image,
          border_color,
        } = recommendationsArray[i];

        const params = [
          id,
          recommendation_attribute,
          recommendation_value,
          segment_id,
          target_attribute,
          target_value,
          is_deleted,
          updated_at,
          name,
          image,
          border_color,
        ];

        try {
          txn.executeSql(
            upsertRecommendations,
            params,
            (_tx, _results) => {
              resolve({ error: false, results: insertStatus });
            },

            error => {
              crashlytics().recordError(error);
              if (__DEV__) {
                console.log('sqlUpsertRecommendations error:', error);
              }
              const { notInserted } = insertStatus;
              insertStatus.inserted = notInserted + 1;

              if (1 + i === recommendationsArray.length) {
                resolve({ error: false, ...error, results: insertStatus });
              }
            },
          );
        } catch (e) {
          crashlytics().recordError(e);
        }
      }
    });
  });
};
```

I am learning async await and people in our team are using it like

```
const testFunction = async () => { 
....
await sqlUpsertRecommendations(parsedData)
```

But vscode is saying

> 'await' has no effect on the type of this expression.

I just need idea how to best approach and use this kind of code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to actually `return` the `new Promise`, then you can `await` it. If you don't, you just start a Promise and then immediately return `undefined`, and you can't `await undefined`.

```js
const sqlUpsertRecommendations = recommendationsArray => {
// eslint-disable-next-line no-new

  return new Promise(resolve => {
    // ... rest of code
```

`async` is really just syntactic sugar for creating and using `Promise`s. An `async` function just returns a new `Promise` and that's what `await` cares about, so `await` will work if you have a normal function that returns a `Promise`.

Comment: What `await` really do is wait for the promise to be fulfilled or rejected The promise doesn't have to come from the function. `async` functions automatically return promises.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski hello can provide a code please i dont understand it well? my sqlUpsertRecommendations is not async

Comment: @KonradLinkowski If you just changed this to an `async` function, it would return an `Promise` that immediately resolves to `undefined`. If you converted this fully to an `async` function, you would still have to create a `new Promise` eventually since `dbConfig.transaction` uses callbacks instead of promises

Comment: Right, so the answer for the first part of the question in the title is Yes - the function doesn't need to be declared `async` for the `await` of its result to be meaningful, it just have to *return* (not just declare) a `Promise`